# Linux service and saving logs into a file

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, microservices

Using RPi, I am sending and receiving data to and from ESP32 at the same time. I have two `.py` scripts and two linux services. Before I created the services the `.py` scripts were working correctly (but not at the same time, thats why I am making services), the `rec_data.log` contained data from ESP32.

They work in parallel (checked via `systemctl status` for both services), also ESP32 is getting the message from RPi. But the part with saving data from ESP into a `.log` file on RPi is not working.

I used `StandardOutput=...` and the `rec_data.log` file is getting created, but remains empty. It should get a "TEST" string per 5 seconds.

My `receive.service` looks as follow:

```
[Unit]
Description=Test Service
#After=multi-user.target
#Conflicts=getty@tty1.service

[Service]
#Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/receive.py
StandardOutput=append:/home/pi/rec_data.log # tried without these two lines also (didnt work)
StandardError=append:/home/pi/rec_err.log # tried without these two lines also (didnt work)
#Restart=always
#StandardInput=tty-force

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

My `receive.py` script looks as follow:

```
from bluetooth import *
file = open("rec_data.log", "a") // tried to give the full path to the file also (didnt work)
def rx_and_echo():
    while True:
        data1 = sock.recv(buf_size)
        if data1:
            data1 = str(data1)
            data1 = data1[2:-1]
            file.write(data1 + '\n')

addr = "E0:E2:E6:CF:BB:AA"
service_matches = find_service(address=addr)
buf_size = 1024

if len(service_matches) == 0:
    print("couldn't find the SampleServer service =(")
    sys.exit(0)

first_match = service_matches[0] 
port = first_match["port"]
name = first_match["name"]
host = first_match["host"]

port = 1 
sock = BluetoothSocket(RFCOMM)
#sock.connect((host, port)) // this is done on send.py so cannot be doubled here

rx_and_echo()
file.close()
sock.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two concept here.

1. you want to write to a file explicitly in `python`
2. you want to redirect the standard output to the same file.

I think also that you problem could come from the python buffering.

Keep the `.service` file and try this:

- use `print` instead of `file.write`
- flush after a write

---

```py
import sys
from bluetooth import *
def rx_and_echo():
    while True:
        data1 = sock.recv(buf_size)
        if data1:
            data1 = str(data1)
            data1 = data1[2:-1]
            print(data1)
            sys.stdout.flush()

addr = "E0:E2:E6:CF:BB:AA"
service_matches = find_service(address=addr)
buf_size = 1024

if len(service_matches) == 0:
    print("couldn't find the SampleServer service =(")
    sys.exit(0)

print('connected')

first_match = service_matches[0] 
port = first_match["port"]
name = first_match["name"]
host = first_match["host"]

port = 1 
sock = BluetoothSocket(RFCOMM)
#sock.connect((host, port)) // this is done on send.py so cannot be doubled here

rx_and_echo()
sock.close()
```

Comment: not printing the data to the file actually :/